# Global Variables not being accessed by Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, redux

I am getting a ReferenceError: NC_SETTINGS is not defined.

```
"use strict";


import forOwn from 'lodash/object/forOwn';
import { assert, expect, should } from 'chai';
import { spy } from 'sinon';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {
    REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST,
    REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
    REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_FAILURE
} from 'actions/types';
import nock from 'nock';
import Actions from 'actions';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

var NC_SETTINGS = require('/home/tai/Gravitate/nc-app/taimoor/settings').NC_SETTINGS;
describe('forgot password async actions', () => {
    afterEach(()=> {
        nock.cleanAll();
    });

    //mockActions();
    //console.log(Actions.addPasswordResetRequest().addPasswordResetRequestAPI());
    it('should show a request for a password reset and that it succeeded ', (done) => {

        console.log(NC_SETTINGS);
        nock('http://localhost:8080/')
        .post('/password-reset-requests')
        .reply(200);
        var email = "test@email.com";
        const expectedActions= [
            {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST},
            {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_SUCCESS}
        ];
        const store = mockStore({}, expectedActions, done);
        store.dispatch(Actions.addPasswordResetRequest());
        //unMockActions();
        //
        //console.log(actions);
        //expect(actions.addPasswordResetRequest("email")).to.equal(expectedAction);

  });

});
```

So when I console.log NC_SETTINGS, it does show. However, when I run store.dispatch(Actions.addPasswordResetRequest), I get the NC_SETTINGS is not defined. The reason why I thought importing NC_SETTINGS could potentially work is because it worked for importing isomorphic-fetch, I had a similar issue.

Is there a way to import global variables into MochaJs such that my action can access NC_SETTINGS?

I should mention that store.dispatch(Actions.addPasswordResetRequest()) links to an actions file, which dispatches to an api call in a js file. That js file at the end is where NC_SETTINGS resides, and where the error is being called. In the browser, this works fine.

Is there a way to have a list of global variables and add them while testing in Mocha?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, but you can use:

```
global.NC_SETTINGS = ...
```

to set it as a nodejs global variable. And this should be picked up in `Actions`.

However global variables are something you want to avoid for many, many reasons.  Instead you probably want to do some kind of dependency injection. Two possibilities are:

1. Implement the `Actions` as a class, and instantiate it where it's used passing `NC_SETTINGS` as a construction parameter.
2. Use the [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) module. In that case NC_SETTINGS could be a top level variable in the `Actions` module, but not a global variable.